# How to calculate this limit of a function defined in pieces?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Calculate $$\lim_{x\rightarrow~ 0} f(x)$$ where

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} x~\textrm{if}~x\in \mathbb{Q}\\x^2 ~\textrm{if}~x\notin \mathbb{Q} \end{matrix}\right.$$

To me it seems like the function will have limit $0$ but I'm not sure how to show/prove it.

Comment: Are you using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition or the sequential definition of limit?

Comment: Yes I am meant to use that to prove the limit I think.

Comment: @Christof What is "that" in your answer to Git??

Comment: I asked you "A or B", you answered me "yes". That's what I do when I don't want to answer my girlfriend's questions.

Comment: Oh I misread your comment. I can use either on my course but I think epsilon-delta is preferred. I believe I have shown the limit to be true for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ by taking $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: Can you prove that $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous at $0$?

Comment: Yes I think so, taking $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$ works does it not?

Comment: @Christof Yes. I suppose you already know the limit exists and it is $0$. So now just follow the definition.You wish to prove that
$$\mathop{\forall}_{\varepsilon >0}\,\mathop{\exists}_{\delta >0}\,\mathop{\forall}_{x\in \mathbb R}\left(|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|<\varepsilon\right).$$ Start by taking an arbitrary positive number $\varepsilon$. Now you wish to find $\delta$.You already have found two somewhat relevant $\delta$'s, namely $\varepsilon$ and $\sqrt \varepsilon$. Can you somehow use this information to find a suitable $\delta$?

Comment: Can't you use $\delta=\epsilon$ for when $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$ for when $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$. Then you have the limit is $0$ in both cases so the limit must be $0$. Or would you need to say something like let $\delta:=\min\{\epsilon, \sqrt{\epsilon}\}$?

Comment: @Christof You can't do the first thing you suggest because you need to decide what $\delta$ must be before even thinking of any $x$. Your last idea is good. Try it.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. The only part I'm struggling with now is how to write it up using the min. I think that both inequalities are satisfied whenever delta is equal to the min so the limit must be zero for x in Q or not in Q so the limit is zero but I can't write it properly?

Comment: So take $\delta:=\min\{\varepsilon, \sqrt{\varepsilon}\}$.Now you need to prove the universal statement $$\mathop{\forall}_{x\in \mathbb R}\left(|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|<\varepsilon\right).$$ How does one prove a universal statement? One takes an arbitrary element, say $x$.Now you need to prove the statement $$|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)|<\varepsilon.$$ It's a conditional statement, how does one prove a conditional statement? You assume the antecedent and try to prove the consequent. So suppose $|x|<\delta$.

Comment: Now you wish to prove that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$. Well, either $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=x^2$. It's a proof by cases. Finish it.

Comment: Okay so if $f(x)=x$ then $|f(x)|<\delta=\epsilon$ as required.

Or

if $f(x)=x^2$ then $|f(x)|=x^2<\delta={\sqrt{\epsilon}}^2=\epsilon$ as required.  Is this correct.

Comment: No, it's not (necessarily) true that $\delta=\varepsilon$, you yourself called it: $\delta=\min\{\varepsilon, \sqrt{\varepsilon}\}$.

Comment: I have no idea how to write it then :( Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $0\le|f(x)|\le|x|$ for every $x\in[-1,1].$ From squeeze theorem you get:

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} |f(x)|=0,$$

which is equivalent to:

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=0.$$